# check free internal storage (disk space) left on Android device every 30 seconds in a service

Tags: android

check free internal storage (disk space) left on Android   every 30 seconds

I need to check free internal storage (disk space) that is available in android how can we do this programmatically in a  service?

Comment: You can use **RxAndroid** for such scenarios where Timer Operator are useful to execute such kind of operations. Reference: [http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timer.html](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timer.html)

Comment: Are you asking how to check storage space or how to run a scheduled call via a service?

Comment: run a scheduled call via a service

Answer (score 0):

```
class myService extends Service
{
MyThreads mt;
public myService() {
        mt = new MyThreads();
    }
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (mt.getState() == Thread.State.NEW) {
            mt.start();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }


class MyThreads extends Thread {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void run() {
            while (true) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                    long freeBytesInternal = new File(ctx.getFilesDir().getAbsoluteFile().toString()).getFreeSpace();
                    log.i(TAG,"Avalable Space ::"+freeBytesInternal);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```